# Convert numeric string into an integer but ignore non-numeric strings

Tags: javascript, html

I created the following code because I'm getting values from an input that only accepts numbers and spaces, and I want to convert and add each number from the input while disregarding the spaces:

```
// variable textArea is the value from the input
let textArea = document.getElementById("numVal").value;
let regex = /^[0-9\s]*$/;
if(regex.test(textArea) == true) {
  let val = Number(textArea)  //Used this to convert the string into integer
  res1.innerHTML = textArea;
}
// The function that add all numbers is still lacking.
```

The numbers are collected, but when I add a space, it displays `NaN`.  So, for example, if the `textArea` is `10`, then it will display `10`, but when the `textArea` is `10`  (with space), it will display `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match all digits to get an array of digit strings, then turn each string into a number and add them up.

```
const { value } = document.getElementById("numVal");
if (/^[\d\s]*$/.test(value)) {
    const total = (value.match(/\d+/g) || [])
        .map(Number)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    res1.textContent = total;
}
```

It might be better UI-wise to prevent non-digits and non-spaces from being entered to begin with, rather than to fail to calculate when unexpected characters are encountered.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's finally working! :D